# This.setState does not set state even after binding `this`

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, this, bind

I am currently building a new react project and I am having trouble setting state. I am making an ajax request to my backend to grab information, and then trying to set state, however, once I get out of the ajax scope, the state is not saved. I am binding `this` to ajax request but still no dice. The following is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import SearchForm from './SearchForm.js';

class Main extends Component {
  constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {
    actors: [],
    genres: [],
    directors: [],
  }
    this.getMovieInformation = this.getMovieInformation.bind(this);
}
getMovieInformation(movieName){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3001/get_movie_data',
    data: {name: movieName}
  }).done(function(response){
     this.setState({
       actors: response.movieData.Actors.split(','),
       genres: response.movieData.Genre.split(','),
       writers: response.movieData.Writer.split(','),
       directors: response.movieData.Director.split(',')
     })
  }.bind(this));
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchForm getMovieInformation={this.getMovieInformation}/>
    </div>
  )
}
}

export default Main;
```

The funny thing is that I have done the same method of setting state inside ajax responses before (I also set bind(this) to the request) and my state remained outside of the ajax scope.

I've looked at other stackoverflow articles, everyone keeps saying to bind(this) after the ajax request, which I've been doing, There aren't any syntax errors, at least that I am aware of. Am I doing something wrong here?? This method has worked every time.

Comment: Have you tried making a function outside of the Ajax call, binding that in the constructor and calling it with 'response' as the input?

Comment: Yes, that was the first way I tried. no dice.

Comment: Can you show us your request in dev tools? Are you sure response.movieData.Actors etc. are being returned.

Comment: If you just use an arrow function for getMovieInformation it'll get bound to this automatically and you don't have to worry about this problem.

Comment: Can you check what the request is returning? And also try logging or debugging the this object to see if it has the context that you need

Comment: I actually just got it to work! Thanks, everyone! Two things were happening: 1) I completely forgot to take ajax's async into mind and 2) I was placing my debugger prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

This line `this.sendMovieTitleToAPI = this.getMovieInformation.bind(this);` shouldn't it be `this.getMovieInformation = this.getMovieInformation.bind(this);`?
I also don't think you should be binding `this` in the ajax call.

I recommend using `axios` for making HTTP requests to your server.

Comment: sorry, i made a typo when copying over the code to stack. it is `this.getMovieInformation = this.getMovieInformation.bind(this);`.

Comment: I'd suggest you use axios or request npm packages to make your api request instead of using jQuery as React doesn't work too well with jQuery.
Also, you could try using Flux or Redux for that.

Comment: can you tell what the fix was?